# NativeScript: How to deploy iOS app to physical device?

Tags: ios, nativescript, telerik-appbuilder

I created an account with Telerik, signed a certificate with Apple Dev Centre and got a mobile provisioning. I used Appbuilder to import the certificate and the provision to my laptop. But I still cannot deploy my app on iOS using

```
tns deploy ios
```

The warning says:

IMPORTANT: Before building for iOS device, verify that you have configured a valid pair of certificate and provisioning profile on your OS X system.

But when I do "appbuilder provision" and "appbuilder certificate", the commands show me they have been successfully imported. I also tried:

```
appbuilder deploy ios --provision '<name>' --certificate '<title>'
```

It says no project found at or above path and neither was a --path specified. But I am in the project folder. :/

Comment: Perhaps you have to add your `TEAM_ID` in `app/App_Resources/iOS/build.xcconfig` file in your project and then to run `tns run ios` for deploying your app. For further instruction you could also review this issue. - https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3125#issuecomment-261890308

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me, I used:

`$ tns deploy ios --device <device-udid>`

Now, beforehand I...

1. Registered my device with Apple

   - Link: developer.apple.com/account/ios/device
2. Created an explicit Bundle ID  with Apple that **matches** the one that Native Script places in the package.json. This is what mine looked like.

   ```
   "nativescript": {
       "id": "org.nativescript.<app-name>",
       "tns-ios": {
           "version": "3.0.1"
       },
       "tns-android": {
           "version": "3.0.1"
       }
     }
   ```

   - Link: developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle
3. I then made provisioning profile with Apple https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/ that then included the device and Bundle ID that I just made.
4. Then in the file /app/App_Resources/iOS/build.xcconfig

   - Link: developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle

ie.

```
    DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = <Apple-dev-team-name>
    PROVISIONING_PROFILE = <provision-profile-id>
```

- The provison profile is found in User/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
- If there is more than one, sort be creation date and grab the first one
- Then ctrl-click and choose "Rename" copy the ID and paste it into the build.xcconfig file from earlier.

  5. To get the device UDID, you could use iTunes, but {N} makes it easy by running this in the terminal:

`$ tns device ios --available-devices`

- It shows up at the bottom under all the different emulators

i.e.

```
    │#│Device Name│Platform│Device Identifier│ Type │  Status │
    │1│  iPhone   │ iOS    │  <device-udid>  │Device│Connected│
```

6. After all that, run:

`$ tns deploy ios --device <device-name>`

P.S. : Let me know if this works.

Comment: I also had an issue with it still saying Code signing need in iOS 10.3. I solved it strangely by opening xcode, clicking my project, and reselecting my Signing (Debug) and Signing (Release). This then let my use `$ tns deploy ios --device <device-name>`. I do still get "Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error," with a sub error "Linker failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

Comment: The .xcodeproj file is in <app-name>/platforms/ios/

Comment: There has been a fix in the (as of writing) experimental 3.1.0; Link = https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/2874 `npm un -g nativescript && npm cache clean && npm i -g nativescript@next`